# Non virtual destruction of derrived class that has no new fields c++

Tags: c++

If I define base class without virtual destructor (for speed) like:

```
class BaseMessage {
public: std::string msg;
};
```

And than derived classes like:

```
class M1: public BaseMessage {
public: M1() { msg = "Message1"; }
};
```

So they differ only in initialization.
Is there any problem in destruction of derived classes:

```
try{ throw M1(); }
catch(BaseMessage const& message) { std::cerr << message.msg << std::endl; }
```

Comment: Does any of this compile?

Comment: "For speed": did your benchmark tell you that your code is being slowed down due to 1 virtual function call? If not, why do you think this is an issue?

Comment: Code in example edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Throwing** objects in C++ has the same semantics as locally-scoped objects, i.e. the runtime knows the exact type of the object and will call the appropriate destructor, even if it is non-virtual.

This is not the same as when you call `delete` through a pointer, because in that case there is incomplete information about the type of the object at that point.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with **destruction** of objects of type `M1`. However, if you create an object of type `M1` on the heap and you access it through a pointer to `BaseMessage` you cannot **delete** it through that pointer; the behavior is undefined. So:

```
BaseMessage* ptr = new M1;
delete ptr; // undefined behavior
```

So don't do that.

Many people like to guess at what the behavior will be in specific cases. While that can be a fun parlor game, it is not sound engineering. Unless your compiler documents what it does you cannot rely on any particular behavior here, so don't do it.